# Wolframalpha in python with GTTS

Tags: python-2.7, wolframalpha, gtts

I am trying to make a Friday like virtual assistant using this code

```
import os
from gtts import gTTS
import time
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr

while True:
    def speak(text):
        tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
        filename = "voice.mp3"
       tts.save(filename)
       playsound.playsound(filename)

    def get_audio():
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            said = ""

            try:
                said = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print(said)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception: " + str(e))

        return said


    text = get_audio()

    
    if "who are you" in text:
        speak(" I am Monday the  virtual assistant")
```

And i was wondering how to put wolfram alpha in it so i would, say search for ..., then it would speak the answer from wolfram alpha.

Any help would be amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

Install wolframalpha
Then add the following to your code:

```
import wolframalpha

if 'search for ' in text:
  text = text.replace("search for ", "")
  client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
  res = client.query(text)
  print(next(res.results).text)
  speak(next(res.results).text)
```

To use the API, you have to go to the [homepage](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), sign up for an account, create an app and get an app id.
To avoid getting any errors, keep the indentation in your 'speak' function uniform.